# Error while using .ForEach in WinDbg

Tags: windbg

Why am I getting a `Invalid parameter poi(adr+4)` when I run the following command in WinDbg while debugging a dump file?

```
.foreach ( adr { !dumpheap -mt 66df13d4 -short } ) { !do poi(adr+4); }
```

The following shows that the value of `adr` is getting populated just fine.

```
.foreach ( adr { !dumpheap -mt 66df13d4 -short } ) { .echo adr; }
```

I want to get the contents of a .NET string variable that is stored at the 4th offset of a `System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have spaces around `adr` or use `${adr}`.   This is documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563124%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> **Note**   When the string *Variable* appears within *OutCommands*, it must be
>   surrounded by spaces. If it is adjacent to any other text -- even a
>   parenthesis -- it will not be replaced by the current token value,
>   unless you use the [${ } (Alias Interpreter)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566259%28VS.85%29.aspx) token.