# Iterating through !DumpHeap output to read value at memory offset

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks, clr, windbg, crash-dumps

I'm trying to come up with a WinDbg command line expression that takes the output of the `!DumpHeap` command and for each address, reads a 64-bit value from offset `0x08` after the address. I think this is possible (not sure about it) but every attempt I made so far fails with some error.

I searched a lot but most WinDbg articles show simple examples which I can try but my attempts fail.

I have a process dump of an ASP.NET worker process. The process has some memory growth but there's no clear offender so I'm trying to list a number of objects that appear many times in memory. I'm using sos.dll for the managed debugging WinDbg extensions.

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
.foreach(myaddress {!dumpheap -short -mt 000007fe998adea8})
{r @$t0=poi(myaddress+0x8);!do @$t0;.echo ************* myaddress}
```

*Note, that the above command must be on a single line - I only added a line break for better readability here.*

For the above line, WinDbg prints this error: `Couldn't resolve error at 'myaddress+0x8);!do @$t0;.echo ************* 00000001003cb870'`.

I'm trying to iterate through all addresses returned by `!DumpHeap` - each address should go into the `myaddress` variable. Then, for each address, I'm trying to set the `$t0` user register to the value read from `myaddress+0x8`. The `!do` (`!DumpObject`) command would then dump the object at that address.

If I run only (*again, on one line in WinDbg*):

```
.foreach(myaddress {!dumpheap -short -mt 000007fe998adea8})
{!do myaddress;.echo ************* myaddress}
```

I get a list of object dumps but this is one level higher than what I need. I want to drill down one level deeper and dump a particular member of these top-level objects that I'm iterating through.

Is this possible or am I on the wrong track with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display managed objects with certain value in one of the fields in WinDbg using SOS (or SOSEX)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765713/how-to-display-managed-objects-with-certain-value-in-one-of-the-fields-in-windbg)

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ Yes, it could be a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

After further searching, I found that I was using the wrong syntax. According to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909135/error-while-using-foreach-in-windbg) and to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563124%28VS.85%29.aspx), variable names must be surrounded by spaces or must be enclosed in `${...}` to work. After I used the `${}` enclosure, my script started working.

For future reference, here's how to run the script (*keep it on one line in WinDbg*):

```
.foreach(myaddress {!dumpheap -short -mt 000007fe998adea8})
{r @$t0=poi(${myaddress}+0x8);!do @$t0;.echo ************* myaddress}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you need space around the aliases

> .foreach ( place { .shell -ci "!DumpHeap -stat" sed 1,3d | awk "{print
>   $1 }" } ) { .foreach (plays { !DumpHeap -short -mt place } ) { r $t0 =
>   poi( plays + 8 ) ; !do @$t0 ; .echo
>   ========================================= } }