# How to get the root path references to leaked objects in .NET?

Tags: .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, memory-profiling

I have a memory leak in my .NET application. In the meantime I know which objects are leaked. But there should be no references to it. How can I find the reference pathes? Which tool is the right solution for it?

Comment: WinDbg or .Net Memory Profiler (not free). Get a full memory dump and then open it in one of the tools.

Comment: This could be helpful to start (not sure): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102678/iterating-through-dumpheap-output-to-read-value-at-memory-offset

Comment: Also, SOS.dll - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Red gate ANTS Memory profiler and have a look at [Walkthrough: Using ANTS Memory Profiler to track down a memory leak](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough)

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate you like to learn how things work under the hood. This should give you a starting point:

1. Create a [good crash dump for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net).
2. Get [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft. You can install both versions, x86 and x64 so that you can debug both kinds of dumps.
3. Open the crash dump in WinDbg (use correct bitness).
4. [Set up the symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)
5. Load the .NET extension, `.loadby sos clr` (for .NET 4.x, else see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25930140/480982))
6. Find the object you're looking for using `!dumpheap -type MyType`
7. Use `!gcroot` to see whether the object has root references or not.

For specific problems, ask questions using [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) and [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) tags.