# !DumpHeap - possible to disable GC warning?

Tags: .net, service, memory-leaks, windbg, sos

I have a full process dump from an NT service (implemented using C# / .NET 4.5.2) that's in the middle of a GC cycle. When I load it into WinDbg and try to run `!DumpHeap -stat` (or any other variant of `DumpHeap`), I get this warning:

> The garbage collector data structures are not in a valid state for traversal. It is either in the "plan phase," where objects are being moved around, or we are at the initialization or shutdown of the gc heap. Commands related to displaying, finding or traversing objects as well as gc heap segments may not work properly. !dumpheap and !verifyheap may incorrectly complain of heap consistency errors.

Unfortunately, I cannot (easily) get a clean memory dump outside of GC (I obviously don't know when it happens and I need a dump of some manageable size - the process I'm looking at leaks memory and reaches 18 GB sometimes; this is so big that most heap lookups take over 40 minutes in WinDbg.)

This warning message shows up even when I use the `-short` parameter to only generate object addresses (to input them into a WinDbg macro) - unfortunately the words of the warning message are passed as input parameters to the macro and the macros blows up. (The macro is a variant of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28104135/682404) and I'm trying to run `!GCRoot` on a large number of object instances.)

Is there a way to disable this warning message in WinDbg? (`DumpHeap` is part of SOS, so I guess it needs to be disabled there, if possible.)

**Edit**: to make it clear, I get useful output from `DumpHeap` and other commands (which seem mostly consistent), it's just that all output begins with the above warning, even when using `-short`. This means that I cannot fed the output into other commands.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question seems somewhat unclear. Why disable the message? Even if disabled, you still wouldn't be able to use the dumpheap command, because the system is in a state it wasn't designed to handle. A few suggestions: 1) see if any of !EEHeap, !GCHandleLeaks, !heapstat, !verifyheap are of help. 2) try the sosex.dll debug extension (google for it). 3) Google for blogs on debugging GC memory leaks (I found two right away).

Comment: @user2460798 I didn't realize that the question was unclear. I do get useful output from DumpHeap (and other commands), it's just all output begins with that warning, so that the short output versions of the commands cannot be fed into other commands. I'll add that as a detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your question

I understand it is a pity that the `-short` output contains that message. IMHO the message cannot be disabled.

You can use [pykd (Codeplex)](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) to filter the text. You'd need the [`dbgCommand()`](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.3.%20API%20Reference&referringTitle=Documentation#dbgCommand) function to issue the `!dumpheap` command. You'll get back a string with the output of the command and you can then filter the text. Next you could push the text back to the debugger with [`dprint()`](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.3.%20API%20Reference&referringTitle=Documentation#dprint).

### Other ideas

1. Perhaps you want to try [taking a dump when .NET is not in the middle of a garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676732/how-to-capture-a-process-memory-dump-of-a-net-process-when-net-is-not-in-the-m).
2. Speed up things:

   - [sosex](/questions/tagged/sosex) has a `!bhi` command to build a heap index.
   - [netext](https://netext.codeplex.com/) has a `!windex` command to build a heap index. It even has a command similar to `!dumpheap` which can be used in the `.foreach` fashion (from the website):

     ```
     .foreach({$addr} {!windex -short -type *.HttpRequest}){!wselect _url.m_String from {$addr} }
     ```
3. PyKd: While you're at it, you might also rewrite the `.foreach` loop in Python and do the `!do` part in Python as well, allowing you to filter objects based on their content etc. so you might get some time back by using a more intuitive scripting language.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very useful. I didn't consider the possibility of knowing when a GC happens - the computer is a production machine and I have no access to it. I have to go through multiple layers of internal support to get the dump file from it.

Comment: Please try the linked answer before. I didn't have time to check it myself.

Comment: I will. Your answer still looks good - I wasn't aware of pykd and netex. I tried SOSEX in the past but it kept blowing up on me.