# How to capture a dump during a garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, windbg

TLDR: I want to reproducibly capture a crash dump in the middle of a garbage collection.

Details:

In order to be able to better help other people answering questions related to crash dumps that were taken during the process of garbage collection *), I am looking for a way to capture example dumps while .NET is doing garbage collection.

I am not looking for a single "open source" dump which has that effect. Instead I'd like to be able to make it reproducible, so I can capture a series of crash dumps, because I want

- different operating systems (Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10)
- different CLRs (2.0, 4.0)
- different architectures (x86, x64)
- different modes (debug, release)

So an answer should consist of two parts:

1. a demo .NET program that allocates memory and does garbage collection
2. a command or batch script that captures a crash dump at the right time (e.g. using [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx))

*)

We have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905700/dumpheap-possible-to-disable-gc-warning/33912648#33912648) which is about analyzing a crash dump that was captured during a garbage collection.

We also have a question asking the opposite: [How to capture a crash dump when it is not in the middle of garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676732/how-to-capture-a-process-memory-dump-of-a-net-process-when-net-is-not-in-the-m).

Comment: Related: [OpenData: request for Windows crash dumps](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/windows-kernel-or-user-mode-crash-dumps). If such a thing does not exist, I'm willing to build a platform for it. An answer to above question could provide an initial input of 5*2*2*2=40 crash dumps.

Comment: Potential downvoters: I'm just trying to make the world a better place by providing reproducible steps and open data in order to learn from, which should be inline with the intention of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Of course I'll answer the question myself when I find the time to do so. In the meanwhile it might be a nice experiment for someone else and he might learn a lot during the task.

Comment: Don't see any need for this for me in the near future but I'd hope to come across your answer when I do need it. You have my vote but looking at the downvotes, it's a thin line you are walking <g>.